# How to transpose certain columns in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Currently have a dataframe like this:

| RepName | Hours | Reason |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 4 | Research |
| John | 15 | Training |
| Matt | 6 | Project Labor |
| Matt | 10 | Training |

I want to transpose each reason as a column with the Hours values as values like so:

| RepName | Research | Training | Project Labor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 4 | 15 | 0 |
| Matt | 0 | 10 | 6 |

I tried to transpose and melting the dataframe and couldn't figure it out.  Still sort of new to this, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with [`pd.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) like so:

```py
>>> df.pivot_table(index="RepName", columns="Reason", values="Hours", fill_value=0)
Reason   Project Labor  Research  Training
RepName
John                 0         4        15
Matt                 6         0        10
```

Full example:

```py
import pandas as pd

input_data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "RepName": ["John", "John", "Matt", "Matt"],
        "Hours": [4, 15, 6, 10],
        "Reason": ["Research", "Training", "Project Labor", "Training"],
    }
)

output_data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Project Labor": [0, 6],
        "Research": [4, 0],
        "Training": [15, 10],
    },
    index=["John", "Matt"],
)

pivoted = input_data.pivot_table(
    index="RepName",
    columns="Reason",
    values="Hours",
    fill_value=0,
)

assert output_data.equals(pivoted)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a [`.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) operation. The point of a pivot is to turn some subset of rows into their own columns.

```py
out = df.pivot(index='RepName', columns='Reason', values='Hours').fillna(0)
Reason   Project Labor  Research  Training
RepName                                   
John               0.0       4.0      15.0
Matt               6.0       0.0      10.0

print(out)
Reason   Project Labor  Research  Training
RepName                                   
John               0.0       4.0      15.0
Matt               6.0       0.0      10.0
```

If you're unfamiliar with `pandas.Index` that has names, you can get a more familiar result by removing the name from the column index and resetting the row index:

```py
out = (
    df.pivot(index='RepName', columns='Reason', values='Hours')
    .rename_axis(columns=None)
    .reset_index()
    .fillna(0)
)

print(out)
  RepName  Project Labor  Research  Training
0    John            0.0       4.0      15.0
1    Matt            6.0       0.0      10.0
```